# Expo React-Native Web Browser Back Button

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo

I'm looking at using React-Native and Expo to build a web app. The only real issue I'm running into is allowing the use of the browser back button. I'm currently using `@react-navigation/native` to navigate between screens.

Unfortunately, when changing screens, the browser doesn't seem to register this as a change of page and so the browser back button never works. I could certainly use the standard back button used within the app to navigate back but I'd like people to be able to use the browser back button as that's more intuitive. I'm using the following in my App.js:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
...
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Settings"
      component={SettingsScreen}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
)
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <App />
  );
};
```

**So, is it possible using Expo and React-Native to allow the use of the browser back button for apps built for the web?**

Answer (score 0):

[Expo Router](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/introduction/) is going to be the solution. it works on native and web both.

> Expo Router uses "links" to move between pages in the app. By default, links "push" routes onto the navigation stack. It follows the same rules as navigation.navigate(). This means that the previous screen will be available when the user navigates back.